# PL/SQL CRUD matrix from a source code

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, crud

I am trying to create a CRUD matrix for my function from a source code of that function, so I created a procedure that will read a source code.

```
create or replace procedure test_ 
IS
  CURSOR c_text is 
    SELECT USER_SOURCE.TEXT 
      FROM USER_SOURCE 
     WHERE USER_SOURCE.name='TEST_FUNCTION' 
       AND USER_SOURCE.type='FUNCTION';
     order by line;

  v_single_text varchar2(4000);
  v_tmp_text varchar2(10000) := ' ';
begin
  open c_text;
  loop
   fetch c_text into v_single_text;
   exit when c_text%notfound;
   v_tmp_text := v_tmp_text|| chr(10) || rtrim(v_single_text);
   dbms_output.put_line(v_single_text);
  end loop;
  close c_text;
end test_;
```

And that works very good for me, I get the source code of my desired function. It's a very simple function and I use this to learn PL/SQL. Output of that procedure look's like this.

```
function test_funkction Return varchar2
IS
  kpp_value varchar2(20); 
begin
  select KPP 
    into kpp_value 
    from CUSTOMER 
   where CUSTOMER_ID = 200713;

  dbms_output.put_line (kpp_value);
  Return kpp_value;
end test_function;
```

Now, how to parse the string I've got in the output to get a desired result, my result should be like this

```
==TABLE_NAME==========OPERATIONS==

  CUSTOMER              - R - -

==================================
```

Now I have managed to do it.

But it will only work with my simple function, now I want to make a procedure that will work with any function.
Source code below.

```
create or replace procedure test_


IS


v_string_fnc varchar2(10000) := UPPER('function test_function



Return varchar2

IS

kpp_value varchar2(20);



  begin



  select KPP into kpp_value from CUSTOMER where CUSTOMER_ID = 200713;



  dbms_output.put_line (kpp_value);



 Return kpp_value;



 end test_function;');


 v_check PLS_INTEGER;


 CURSOR c_text is
 SELECT USER_SOURCE.TEXT
 FROM USER_SOURCE
 WHERE USER_SOURCE.name = 'TEST_FUNCTION'
 AND USER_SOURCE.type = 'FUNCTION'
 order by line;


 v_single_text varchar2(4000);
 v_tmp_text    varchar2(10000) := ' ';


 /*v_string      varchar2(10000);*/


 insert_flag char := '-';
 read_flag   char := '-';
 update_flag char := '-';
 delete_flag char := '-';
 empty_space char(34) := '                             ';
 underline   char(42) := '==========================================';


 /*v_txt         varchar2(10000) := ' ';*/


 result_table varchar2(1000) := '/';


 begin


 open c_text;


 loop
 fetch c_text
 into v_single_text;
 exit when c_text%notfound;
 v_tmp_text := v_tmp_text || chr(10) || rtrim(v_single_text);

/* print source code*/
/*dbms_output.put_line(v_single_text);*/

 end loop;


 close c_text;


 /*DELETE SEARCH*/


 v_check := instr(v_string_fnc, 'DELETE ');


 if v_check < 1 then
 dbms_output.put_line('THERE IS NO DELETE COMMAND');
 else
 dbms_output.put_line('THERE IS A DELETE COMMAND');
 delete_flag  := 'D';
 v_check      := instr(v_string_fnc, 'FROM ');
 v_check      := v_check + 5;
 result_table := substr(v_string_fnc, v_check);
 result_table := substr(result_table, 0, instr(result_table, ' '));
 dbms_output.put_line('TABLE AFFECTED BY DELETE: ' || result_table);
 end if;


 /*SELECT SEARCH*/


 v_check := instr(v_string_fnc, 'SELECT ');
 if v_check < 1 then
 dbms_output.put_line('THERE IS NO READ COMMAND');
 else
 dbms_output.put_line('THERE IS A READ COMMAND');
 read_flag    := 'R';
 v_check      := instr(v_string_fnc, 'FROM ');
 v_check      := v_check + 5;
 result_table := substr(v_string_fnc, v_check);
 result_table := substr(result_table, 0, instr(result_table, ' '));
 dbms_output.put_line('TABLE AFFECTED BY READ: ' || result_table);

 end if;


 /*UPDATE SEARCH*/
 v_check := instr(v_string_fnc, 'UPDATE ');
 if v_check < 1 then
 dbms_output.put_line('THERE IS NO UPDATE COMMAND');
 else
 dbms_output.put_line('THERE IS A UPDATE COMMAND');
 update_flag  := 'U';
 v_check      := instr(v_string_fnc, 'FROM ');
 v_check      := v_check + 5;
 result_table := substr(v_string_fnc, v_check);
 result_table := substr(result_table, 0, instr(result_table, ' '));
 dbms_output.put_line('TABLE AFFECTED BY UPDATE: ' || result_table);

 end if;


 /*INSERT SEARCH*/
 v_check := instr(v_string_fnc, 'INSERT ');
 if v_check < 1 then
 dbms_output.put_line('THERE IS NO CREATE COMMAND');
 else
 dbms_output.put_line('THERE IS A CREATE COMMAND');
 insert_flag  := 'C';
 v_check      := instr(v_string_fnc, 'FROM ');
 v_check      := v_check + 5;
 result_table := substr(v_string_fnc, v_check);
 result_table := substr(result_table, 0, instr(result_table, ' '));
 dbms_output.put_line('TABLE AFFECTED BY CREATE: ' || result_table);
 end if;
 dbms_output.put_line(' ');
 dbms_output.put_line('==========' || 'TABLE_NAME' || '==========' ||
                   'OPERATIONS' || '==');
 dbms_output.put_line(empty_space || insert_flag || read_flag ||
                   update_flag || delete_flag);
 dbms_output.put_line(underline);


 end test_;
```

With that procedure I can extract and output my code, dbms needs a bit clean up but it will give the result I need.
Now a few questions, how to put a source code of my function to a variable that is not predefined, here is v_string_fnc but it needs to be predefined to work.
And how to link a certain operation with the table, here in my example is easy, one SELECT and keyword FROM that gives me a name of table.
Struggling continues

Comment: This is not a simple problem. You have to analyse the PL/SQL manually to determine this - you might be able to get an approximation by doing some kind of dumbed-down parsing of the code, but it will be complex and imperfect. And that's ignoring the complexity introduced by things like code in comments, and dynamic SQL.

Comment: For example, if you search the code for the table name `CUSTOMER`, you now have to work out what context it's in - e.g. is it in a query, is it in an update statement, or is it just a column name or variable name that has nothing to do with the table?

Comment: Another approach is to use a run-time analysis - i.e. set up a set of unit tests that exercise every line of code in your program, start a trace, then run your test cases. You might then be able to analyse the trace file to determine which tables are queried and updated. Obviously this method will only work if you can set up the test cases sufficiently to run every line of code.

Comment: Yes, I know, and I am aware that this is a complicated thing, and I am stuck with it. Maybe to search for a keyword FROM and cut everything after FROM to the second blank space after it, but how to connect that with an operation SELECT?

Comment: You could query against `USER_DEPENDENCIES` with the name of a procedure or function to see what it depends on and you don't have to parse the text of the code, but I am not quite sure how you can determine if it is a read/write dependency. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/dependencies.htm

Comment: @NebojsanCili: You could try building a DML parser, although you'd have to be sure to strip out all comments form the function first and then also account for statements that include reading and writing such as `INSERT...SELECT` and `UPDATE...SELECT`.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use dependencies table, due to restrictions in my task, it's considered that dependencies are the easy way out. But I can't see the easy way out of this :)

Comment: I have updated my code, and my problems as well :)) But I think that I'm going the right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bigger part it's done, just a tuning after this.

```
v_check := instr2(v_string_fnc, 'DROP ');

if v_check > 0 then

  delete_flag  := 'D';
  v_check      := instr2(v_string_fnc, 'TABLE ', v_check);
  v_check      := v_check + 6;
  result_table := substr(v_string_fnc, v_check);
  rest_string  := result_table;
  result_table := substr(result_table, 0, instr(result_table, ' '));
  result_table := rtrim(result_table);
  result_table := rtrim(result_table, ';');
  merge into result_set
  using dual
  on (tables_used = result_table)
  when matched then
    update set drop_operation = delete_flag
  when not matched then
    insert
      (tables_used, drop_operation)
    values
      (result_table, delete_flag);

  while v_check > 0 loop

    v_check := instr2(rest_string, 'DROP ');

    if v_check > 0 then
      delete_flag  := 'D';
      v_check      := instr2(rest_string, 'TABLE ', v_check);
      v_check      := v_check + 6;
      result_table := substr(rest_string, v_check);
      rest_string  := result_table;
      result_table := substr(result_table, 0, instr(result_table, ' '));
      result_table := rtrim(result_table);
      result_table := rtrim(result_table, ';');
      merge into result_set
      using dual
      on (tables_used = result_table)
      when matched then
        update set drop_operation = delete_flag
      when not matched then
        insert
          (tables_used, drop_operation)
        values
          (result_table, delete_flag);
    end if;
  end loop;
end if;
```